# How do I stop from getting notified twice when I get a text to my Google Voice number?

Tags: sms, notifications, google-voice

When I receive a text message to my Google voice number, I get a notification from my text application, as well as the Google Voice application. It would seem that the message is being forwarded to my cell number, but I've turned off text forwarding in the Voicemail & Text settings.  Is there another setting that I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Google Voice settings (on the web, not the phone app), under phones, select your mobile number, and Edit.  Uncheck "Receive SMS on this phone"

Comment: This is a bad idea. It will solve your problem but it will also make it so that if the Google Voice app ever crashes or you are in an area without data coverage, you will not get your text messages. It is much better to leave this unchecked and then uncheck the "Notifications via text message" box in the Google Voice app on your phone. This ensures that you don't get double-notifications, but still get text messages if the Google Voice app can't connect.

Comment: Didn't realize that. Voting your answer up, mine down.

Comment: Moto DROID v1 with latest GV.  Notifications via text message is unchecked, phone is set as Receive Text Messages in GV web settings.  This causes double-notification (triple if also getting e-mail notifications of new text messages).

Comment: @JadeMason: In the Google Voice app settings, there's an area where you can select the phone number of the current phone. Is that set correctly?

Comment: @Rohan: Yes, the number under 'This phone's number' appears correctly.

Comment: @Rohan: I think you have the option between the app's notifications or SMS, but it's a trade off.  With the former, as you said, you have to be where you have data and the app must be running.  But with the latter, you are using SMS counting towards your cell plan's limit.  Conceivably, you can use a cell plan with data but no SMS by using GVoice for texts.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have updated to the latest version of the Google Voice application in the Market. Then open the app on your phone.

Go to: Settings > Sync and notifications. Uncheck the "Notifications via text message" box. Back all the way out, and just for good measure, reboot your phone.

Comment: After seeing JadeMason's comment on Paul Roub's answer I'm kind of unsure about this now. I know it works for me, but can't be sure it's the best way to do things.